# Concatenate smarty variable with foreach

Tags: smarty

In a .tpl file, I'm using a smarty foreach to concatenate values from an array, separated by pipes "|" :

```
{foreach from=$attachments item=attachment}{$attachment.file}|{/foreach}
```

This writes : *test1.mp3|test2.mp3|test3.mp3|*

Now... I need to pass this result as a variable in an *href* link.
The problem is I can't include my foreach inside the *a href* tag.

Also I tried to assign this result to a new smarty variable but can't figure how to do it.

Any help would be great. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
{assign var=result value=''}
{foreach from=$attachments item=attachment}
    {assign var=temp value=$attachment.file}
    {assign var=result value=$result$temp|}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: It's thing I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now concat is {assign var=result value="{$result}{$temp}"}